# Mapping A List of Enum to A Field in PostgreSQL With Hibernate/Spring Data

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data

There are quite many samples of mapping an array or list of a primitive data type such as integer or string to a database field in PostgreSQL with Hibernate. I am wondering whether it is possible to map a list of Enum to a database field without an additional DB table in PostgreSQL with Hibernate or not. Here is one of use case.

```
public enum Language {
    EN, FR, ZH
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
   private long id;        

   private List<Language> languages ;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map enum list in **PostgreSQL specific way** you can do the following:

Add [hibernate-types](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-hibernate-types-open-source-project-is-born/) lib to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Add an enum type `languages` to your PostgreSQL database:

```
create type languages as enum (
  'EN', 'FR', 'ZH'
);
```

Map your enum collection with this type:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@TypeDef(name = "pgsql_enum", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
public class Person {

    //...

    @Enumerated(STRING)
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "person_languages", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"), 
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_person_languages_person"))
    @Column(name = "language", columnDefinition = "languages", nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
    private List languages;
}
```

More info about **hibernate-types** lib see on the its author, Vlad Mihalcea, [site](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

If you don't need the PostgreSQL specific way you can map your enum list just like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    //...

    @Enumerated(STRING)
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "person_languages", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"), 
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_person_languages_person"))
    @Column(name = "language", length = 2, nullable = false)
    private List<Language> languages;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I actually am looking for a solution without an additional DB table. If I want to use a table for Language, I would create another Entity class and have a one-to-many relationship from Person. A problem of the approach is performance due to an additional join. In Vlad's array mapping sample, there isn't any additional Entity, or a DB table.